# UseHttpLogging NLOG not writing to file

Tags: nlog

I have an Asp Net Core 6 application which uses Nlog for logging.
I have it configured to write to a log file and a database, which is working fine.
I have Nlog configured in the appsettings.json file as such:

```
     ... removed for brevity
     "internalLogLevel": "Info",
     "rules": [
       {
         "logger": "*",
         "minlevel": "Debug",
         "writeTo": "all-file"
       },
       {
         "logger": "*",
         "minlevel": "Debug",
         "writeTo": "database"
       }
     ],
 "targets": {
   "http-file": {
     "type": "File",
     "fileName": "c:/temp/CosmosAPIProxy-Http_Request-${shortdate}.log",
     "layout": "${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message}|${gdc:item=Application}"
   },
   "all-file": {
     "archiveEvery": "Day",
     "archiveFileName": "c:/temp/logs/log.{#}.txt",
     "archiveNumbering": "Rolling",
     "fileName": "c:/temp/CosmosAPIProxy-nlog-${shortdate}.log",
     "layout": "${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message}|${gdc:item=Application}",
     "maxArchiveFiles": "7",
     "type": "File"
   },
   "database": {
     "type": "Database",
     "connectionString": "server=CosmosLog;database=CosmosServiceHealth;User Id=logger;Password=logger;",
     "dbProvider": "System.Data.SqlClient",
     "keepConnection": "true",
     "commandText": "INSERT INTO ServiceLog (ServiceId,ServiceName,ServiceLocation, Route, Message, LogLevel, CorrelationID, Url, StackTrace, Exception, ExceptionType, DateTime, HostName ) VALUES (@ServiceId, @ServiceName, @ServiceLocation, @Route, @Message, @LogLevel, @CorrelationID, @Url, @StackTrace, @Exception, @ExceptionType, @DateTime, @HostName)",
     ...
   }
```

I want to add UseHttpLogging middleware to the app.  I followed the instructions here:
https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/HTTP-Request-Logging#usehttplogging-introduced-with-net6

```
Now my configuration looks like this:

             "rules": [
               {
                 "logger": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware",
                 "minLevel": "Info",
                 "writeTo": "http-file"
               },
               {
                 "logger": "*",
                 "minlevel": "Debug",
                 "writeTo": "all-file"
               },
               {
                 "logger": "*",
                 "minlevel": "Debug",
                 "writeTo": "database"
               }
             ],
            "targets": {
              "http-file": {
                "type": "File",
                "fileName": "c:/temp/CosmosAPIProxy-Http_Request.log",
                "layout": "type=JsonLayout includeEventProperties=true IncludeScopeProperties=true"          
},
        
        ... Rest of file
```

I'm finding that UseHttpLogging is logging to the console, but will not write to the file configured in the Http-File target.

Nothing is showing up in the internalLogFile, and no configuration exceptions are being thrown.

What am I missing?

Some more Info.
I do have throwConfigExceptions set to true.  No errors are being reported.  Here is part of the log that shows the target - notice that http-file appears to be configured correctly.

```
--- NLog configuration dump ---
Debug Targets:
Debug AsyncWrapper_FileTarget(Name=all-file)
Debug AsyncWrapper_DatabaseTarget(Name=database)
Debug AsyncWrapper_FileTarget(Name=http-file)
Debug Rules:
Debug logNamePattern: (:All) levels: [ Debug Info Warn Error Fatal ] writeTo: [ all-file ]
Debug logNamePattern: (:All) levels: [ Debug Info Warn Error Fatal ] writeTo: [ database ]
Debug logNamePattern: (Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware:Equals) levels: [ Trace Debug Info Warn Error Fatal ] writeTo: [ http-file ]
Debug --- End of NLog configuration dump ---
Info Validating config: TargetNames=all-file, database, http-file, ConfigItems=79 ConfigSection=NLog
Debug Unused target checking is started... Rule Count: 3, Target Count: 3
Debug Unused target checking is completed. Total Rule Count: 3, Total Target Count: 3, Unused Target Count: 0
```

Comment: Think you should enable `"throwConfigExceptions: true`, because this is not a valid layout `"layout": "type=JsonLayout includeEventProperties=true IncludeScopeProperties=true" },`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json

Comment: Rolf Kristensen:  Thanks for the response.  I do have throwConfigExceptions: true enabled.  The log file is showing no exceptions.  I updated the post to show some of what is being logged.  I have tried multiple layout configurations, event those shown in the link you provided, none of which seem to work.  I should be able to define just the Type and file location and leave the Layout undefined.  This still does not work.

Comment: Think you should reduce your question to absolute minimum. Only the `http-file` without specifying any Layout (use default-layout), since this [NET6 example](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/tree/master/examples/ASP.NET%20Core%206/ASP.NET%20Core%206%20NLog%20Example) starts writing output from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware` when adding `app.UseHttpLogging();`.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.  Started with a brand new project and then made small incremental changes.  Ended up getting it working.

Comment: Glad you found a solution to your problem.